# System boots into Windows without showing Grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, lenovo

I am using Lenovo Legion Y720 laptop. I have been using dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 for about 6 months now and have not had any problems. When I restarted my laptop this morning, it automatically logs into Windows 10 without showing the option (the dark pink screen - GRUB loader) to log into Ubuntu at all.

I tried going into UEFI mode by hitting Esc/Shift multiple times but neither of them works. It seems to me that the laptop is only detecting Windows as the only OS and not Ubuntu.
I have important work saved onto my Ubuntu partition. Please help me in getting the Ubuntu working again. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Try editing boot order from BIOS and positioning Ubuntu as first record.

Comment: Thank You @MKay. I did it using command line and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem in case it helps anyone.

1. Open the command line as administrator and run the following command:

   `Bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`
2. Restart the system. GRUB loading screen will show up as before.